# How to include files relative to the current executing script in psql?

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL script (say, `MAIN.sql` in `~/sql/`) which has lines like

```
\i components/helper-functions.sql
```

This include works fine if the $PWD is the same as the directory of my script (`~/sql/`), but if it is not, it looks for the included file relative to the $PWD instead of relative to `MAIN.sql`.

So if I call the script from `~/`, it would look for `~/components/helper-functions.sql` and not for `~/sql/components/helper-functions.sql`.

I think a new `\ir` directive is going to be included in 9.2 for exactly this problem, but I'm running 8.3

Comment: You are talking about psql (the client), not PostgreSQL per se, right?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Pass the directory name in as a psql variable and use that to assemble the absolute path to included files, e.g.,

```
$ cat ./tmp/foo.sql
\echo 'This is foo.'
\set abs_bar_sql :DIR '/bar.sql'
\i :abs_bar_sql

$ cat ./tmp/bar.sql
\echo 'This is bar.'

$ psql -f ./tmp/foo.sql -v DIR=$PWD/tmp
This is foo.
This is bar.
```

It's not pretty, but that's why `\ir` is being added after all.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, definitely not pretty when there are 20+ components being included :/